# Как подключиться к готовой базе данных?

Tags: android

Есть база данных с таблицами и полями,я её сразу положу в приложение, можно ли её использовать как созданную с нуля? (Например добавлять свои поля?) Или же её сначала необходимо скопировать в свою таблицу перед использованием? И как вообще лучше работать с внешней БД?

Comment: Сразу вопрос - что делать, если до базы нет доступа?

Comment: @Vesper Готовую базу я положу в приложение, скачивать её не нужно

Comment: Вы не можете работать с внешней БД - только сделать копию из установочного .apk на устройство, таким образом у вас будет две БД - одна, первоначальная, в папке `/assets`, другая, ее копия, с которой будет работать приложение - читать, добавлять, изменять и удалять записи - в папке `/data/data/<имя пакета>/databases/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То о чем я хотел услышать написал @pavlofff:

Вы не можете работать с внешней БД - только сделать копию из установочного .apk на устройство, таким образом у вас будет две БД - одна, первоначальная, в папке /assets, другая, ее копия, с которой будет работать приложение - читать, добавлять, изменять и удалять записи - в папке /data/data/<имя пакета>/databases/

Answer (score 0):

Положи файл базы данных в папку **assets** своего проекта, и классом подхватывай ее оттуда. Класс должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DBName = "имя_твоей_базы_данных";
    Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String path2DB;
    String path;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBName, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
        path2DB = "/data/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/";
        path = path2DB+DBName;
        openDataBase();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() {
        if(db == null) {
            createDataBase();
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        }
        return db;
    }

    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean existDB = checkDataBase();
        if(!existDB) {
            getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
                return;
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DBName);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer))>0){
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();

    }

public void close() {
    if(db != null) {
        db.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
}
}
```

Comment: Ошибка в строке 13, должно быть `db=openDataBase();`

Comment: @Vesper  ну по сути да, можно, я просто вызывал этот метод в конструкторе ради дергания метода createDataBase();. Работает и так, класс взят из реально работающего проекта с подключаемой БД